# Angular 4 / Laravel / JWT - Create Lock Screen

Tags: php, angular, laravel, jwt

I am working on a personal project that requires "Lock Screen" functionality. And user will enter the PIN pad to log back in.

I have done that with Session based authentication but not really sure how i can do it with Token based authentication using Angular and Laravel JWT

This is how i have done with Session:

```
1. User need to login to the system using his credential information
2. Session started
3. When user need to lock the screen, i set $session->put('lock',true) and the PIN pad shows up. 
4. After the user enter the correct PIN pad then i set back $session->put('lock',false)
```

any suggestions ?

I am new with token based authentication
thanks,